# What is the type of SLOT in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

`digitButtons[i] = createButton (QString::number(i), SLOT(digitClicked()));`

and

```
Button *Calculator::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)    
{  
    Button *button = new Button(text);  
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);  
    return button;  
}
```

That code is from Calculator example of Qt docs.

In this doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html, I couldn't find the type of SLOT.

Where is it mentioned that SLOt is QString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as stated by Starl1ght *SLOT* and *SIGNAL* are macro of the Meta-Object Compiler, that's why they have no data type.

In the example you have mentioned, it's used *const char* * because "SLOT is passed by name" to connection function. Have a look here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect

Hope this briefly clarify a little bit what are SIGNALS and SLOTS.

Answer (score 3):

SLOT and SIGNAL are both macro for qt MOC.
They are defined simply as:

```
#define SLOT(a) "1"#a
#define SIGNAL(a) "2"#a
```

Before compilation stage, MOC will find such lines and generate valid .moc file with c++ code, include them in your project and thus, signal\slots shall work.